# Single Page Website using jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web, routes

I am trying to create a single page web application. But I don't want to mess things up so I wanted to clarify things before I continue in the development.

Lets say that I have this web-app that captures the hashes from the links and I want this hash to be the basis of what the application loads. This will be very simple if I were to just do `if-else` but as I increase the number of links, the code seems to be super messy.

I have thought of creating a `routes.json` file, but I stopped right there. I wonder if there are already apis for this problem. Thank you.

Comment: What is your backend language? Have you considered using an MVC framework?

Comment: Checkout http://angularjs.org/ - It's a JavaScript MVC framework with has tons of features including easy/clean way of handling routes

Comment: hmm, I think your suggestion is not-so related with my question, as for your question, php, and yes, I considered that one.

Comment: "i considered that one" You considered which one? AngularJS or MVC framework? -When I read your response - it sounds like you're responding to the MVC framework. However MVC framework is not a specific language... I guess it would help in your response if you indicated which comment you were responding to.

Answer (score 0):

I"d consider using [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter). I know they have built-in options for routes & setting a base url and such.

Also consider using something such as [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/). It provides some unique features like 2-way-databinding. It incorporates certain features of jQuery (they call it JQlite). And doing ajax calls are super simple. It also has built-in features for routes. You can do deep-linking if you wish, or switch between pages without changing the URL.

I'm in the process of using AngularJS to develop my Single Page App, and using Codeigniter to handle things on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Try out http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/ and http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/. I use these and they work great. It gives the functionality of using hash tags as urls as well as being able to use the back button that would move back to other hash pages.